# generate a files sha1 hash to match githubs in php

Tags: php, git, hash, sha1

I am trying to generate file sha hash's on my local webpage to see if the file version if different from my git repo the code i have now is this:

```
$d = file_get_contents($filefullpath);
$s = strlen($d);
$x = sha1("blob " .$s. "\0" .$d.'');
```

But the sha of my file never matches git;s sha, and i need to do in in pure php code no modules.

Comment: FWIW, your code works for me… is it possible the file is stored in a different encoding?

Comment: i seem to be getting a different filesize from local then repo could this be a windows vs *nix issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the code works but i had to revise it 
Unix text file end each line with a line feed character.
DOS/Windows text files end each line with a carriage return and line feed.

so the answer was

```
$d = str_replace("\r\n","\n",file_get_contents_utf8($filefullpath));
$s = strlen( $d );
$x = sha1("blob " .$s. "\0" .$d);
```